# How can I do a breadth-first search using `find`?

Tags: find

The `-depth` primary to `find` causes it to perform a depth-first search.

However, the default sequence is *not* a breadth-first search.

The default sequence could be informally described as a "depth-first traversal that handles nodes when they are *first* encountered rather than doing so during backtracking."

I have an actual need for breadth first search.  How can I make `find` behave in this way?

---

For illustration, with the following setup:

```
$ mkdir -p alpha/{bravo,charlie,delta}
$ touch alpha/charlie/{alpha,beta,gamma,phi}
```

`find` has the following default behavior:

```
$ find alpha
alpha
alpha/charlie
alpha/charlie/alpha
alpha/charlie/phi
alpha/charlie/beta
alpha/charlie/gamma
alpha/delta
alpha/bravo
```

and with `-depth`, it performs as follows:

```
$ find alpha -depth
alpha/charlie/alpha
alpha/charlie/phi
alpha/charlie/beta
alpha/charlie/gamma
alpha/charlie
alpha/delta
alpha/bravo
alpha
```

However, what I want is the following (fictitious) option:

```
$ find alpha -bfs
alpha
alpha/charlie
alpha/delta
alpha/bravo
alpha/charlie/alpha
alpha/charlie/phi
alpha/charlie/beta
alpha/charlie/gamma
```

In other words I need `find` to process/report on *all* files/dirs at a given depth before proceeding further.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not with `find` (at least, not with only `find`). Do you want only to list the files, or do you want to use other primaries?

Comment: @Gilles, actually I realized that `-bfs` wouldn't be quite what I need...I have a simple script that generates an index to a large GitLab project, suitable for inclusion in the GitLab Wiki.  It makes the headers hierarchically based on directory names.  It works great, except that in the example file structure above it would put `delta` under the `charlie` subheader, instead of under the parent `alpha` header.

Comment: Another odd thing is that my `find` output *is* sorted alphabetically.  No idea why....

Comment: Still, I think `-bfs` *could* come in handy, even if it doesn't perfectly fit this use case.

Comment: I implemented such a tool: [bfs](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs).  It's not 100% feature-compatible with GNU find yet, but it's getting there.

Answer (score 13):

`# cat ./bfind`

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while results=$(find "$@" -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i) && [[ -n $results ]]; do
  echo "$results"
  ((i++))
done
```

This works by increasing the depth of `find` and repeating, I think it may repeat results, but could be filtered easily

Comment: Sorry I did not know about the formatting mechanism.  Anyway, actually it does not repeat I think because it cuts off anything less than mindepth

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with just shell wildcards. Build up a pattern with progressively more directory levels.

```
pattern='*'
set -- $pattern
while [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ "$1" != "$pattern" ]; do
  for file; do
    …
  done
  pattern="$pattern/*"
  set -- $pattern
done
```

This misses dot files. Use `FIGNORE='.?(.)'` in ksh, `shopt -s dotglob` in bash, or `setopt glob_dots` in zsh to include them.

Caveats:

- This will blow up memory if there are a lot of files.
- This traverses symbolic links to directories recursively.

If you want to choose the order or directories and non-directories, and performance isn't critical, you can make two passes and test `[ -d "$file" ]` on each pass.

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I did.

Comment: Nice!  One more almost trivial caveat: It will fail to process a file that is the lone file in a directory if the file is literally named `*`.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard Oh, yes, I forgot to mention that. Use bash or zsh with `nullglob` and use `(($#))` as the loop condition to avoid this edge case.

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe your `find` into a sort that sorts primarily by the number of `/` characters in the pathname. For example,

```
find alpha |
awk '{n=gsub("/","/",$0);printf "%04d/%s\n",n,$0}' |
sort -t/ |
sed 's|[^/]*/||'
```

This uses `awk` to prefix the pathname with the number of slashes, and `sed` to remove this prefix at the end.

Actually, as you probably want the contents of directory `alpha/charlie+` to be listed after `alpha/charlie`, you need to say `sort -t/ -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4` upto the desired depth.

Answer (score -3):

Another answer not based on 'find' but on bash - use the "length of parent directory" first, then sort by alpha.

The answer doesn't quite match as your results have "charlie, bravo, delta" but I wondered if it should be "bravo, charlie, delta" in alpha order.

```
paths_breadth_first() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    dirn=${line%/*}         ## dirname(line)
    echo ${#dirn},$line     ## len(dirn),line
  done | sort -n | cut -d ',' -f 2-
}
```

That produces

```
  $ cat /tmp/yy | paths_breadth_first 
  alpha
  alpha/bravo
  alpha/charlie
  alpha/delta
  alpha/charlie/alpha
  alpha/charlie/beta
  alpha/charlie/gamma
  alpha/charlie/phi
```

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong because `a/b/c/d/e/f` is of greater depth than `foobar/bazqux/f`, yet it's shorter. Sorting by length does not translate to sorting by depth.

Answer (score -3):

If you only need to find files and the concern is ordering rather than speed (i.e. if you have thousands of files you are listing for an interactive prompt), the following simple solution will do:

```
find -depth -type f | tac
```

Comment: No. Test your code after `mkdir -p a/z b/z`. The OP wants to process `a` *and* `b` before *any* `z`.

Comment: right, thank you for the hint, that actually invalidates one of my scripts!

Comment: nevermind, it works in my case because there is a caveat: I am looking only for files. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Technically anything `find` finds is a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), I understand you mean "regular files". The answer still doesn't solve the OP's problem. If there are regular files `a`, `b/B` and `c` then your code guarantees `b` before `B` (and this is what the lack of `-depth` would guarantee without `tac`). The ordering of `a`, `b`, `c` (and thus the ordering of `a`, `B`, `c` if you only want regular files) is [unspecified](https://serverfault.com/a/181815). The OP wants `a` and `c` before `B` for sure. Your code does *not* guarantee this.